# Substitution Variable: Specifying Column Names, Expressions, and Text

Tags: oracle11g

When I type & execute this query in PL/SQL Developer:

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, &column_name
   from employees WHERE &condition ORDER BY &order_column
```

I got the error message:

> **ORA-00936:missing expression.**

Although when I execute this query, variables field prompt up on my screen with three field names respectively `column_name`, `condition` and `order_column`.

After entering the values in the above three fields respectively-- `salary,  >10000, employee/-id`  When I click ok, I get the above mentioned error message.

Can anyone please help to sort out this issue?

Comment: Is order_column part of the selected columns?

Answer (score 1):

If you try to run your query in SQLPlus, it will show you how your  query is transformed by the usage of the values you give to the variables:

```
SQL> select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, &column_name from employees WHERE &condition ORDER BY &order_column;
Enter value for column_name: salary
Enter value for condition: >1000
Enter value for order_column: employee/-id
old   1: select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, &column_name from employees WHERE &condition ORDER BY &order_column
new   1: select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, salary from employees WHERE >1000 ORDER BY employee/-id
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, salary from employees WHERE >1000 ORDER BY employee/-id
                                                                               *
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00936: missing expression
```

So, your query becomes the following:

```
select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, salary from employees
WHERE >1000 ORDER BY employee/-id
```

which is obviously wrong.

You need to give a well format condition ( for example `salary > 1000`) and to use the right column identifiers for the `ORDER BY` clause ( say `employee_id`); for example:

```
SQL> select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, &column_name from employees WHERE &condition ORDER BY &order_column;
Enter value for column_name: salary
Enter value for condition: salary > 10000
Enter value for order_column: employee_id
old   1: select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, &column_name from employees WHERE &condition ORDER BY &order_column
new   1: select employee_id, first_name, last_name, job_id, salary from employees WHERE salary > 10000 ORDER BY employee_id

EMPLOYEE_ID FIRST_NAME           LAST_NAME                 JOB_ID         SALARY
----------- -------------------- ------------------------- ---------- ----------
        100 Steven               King                      AD_PRES         24000
        101 Neena                Kochhar                   AD_VP           17000
...
15 rows selected.

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

Is that your column name?  `employee/-id`?  That may be part of your problem here.

Basically using anything different than:

Alphabets

Numbers (not at start of the column name)

Underscore (_)

is not recommended as it is not a good way to name fields and some datasources might throw errors on other characters.

Comment: Hi Ryan, actually ...it's typo error. The attribute is employee_id. Employee table is default table in SQL developer, pl/SQL developer. In that table, every attribute is named like...EMPLOYEE_ID, FIRST_NAME, LAST_NAME....and so on....You can check by yourself also.